# Upload folders from local system to FTP using Python script

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have to automatically upload folders to an FTP using a Python script. I am able to upload a single file, but not folders with subfolders and files in them. I did a lot of search, but failed. Could some one help me out here? Thanks in advance.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import ftplib
s = ftplib.FTP('serverip','usrname','password') 
file = '/home/rock/test.txt'
ftppath = '/IT'
filename = "rak"
s.cwd(ftppath)
f = open(file,'rb')                
s.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f)         

f.close()                                
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically need to use os.walk() to grab those files and transfer them.

Here's a script I wrote for myself to do much of what your asking.
I wrote it a long time ago, so I'd probably do it differently if I wrote it again, but I get a lot of use out of it.

It imports psftplib, which is a wrapper I wrote for the putty sftp.
Feel free to remove these references, or grab the lib at:
http://code.google.com/p/psftplib/source/browse/trunk/psftplib.py

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
'''This tool will ftp all the files in a given directory to a given location

if the file ftpallcfg.py exists in the directory it will be loaded and the values within it used, 
with the current directory used as the source directory.

ftpallcfg.py file contains the following variables.
===========================
server = <server to ftp to>
username = <Username for access to given server>
remote_dir = <remote server directory>
encrypt= True/False
monitor = True/False
walk = True/False
=========================== 
'''
import ftplib
import os
import getpass
import sys
import time
import socket
import psftplib

__revision__ = 1.11

SLEEP_SECONDS = 1


class FtpAddOns():
    PATH_CACHE = []

    def __init__(self, ftp_h):
        self.ftp_h = ftp_h

    def ftp_exists(self, path):
        '''path exists check function for ftp handler'''
        exists = None
        if path not in self.PATH_CACHE:
            try:
                self.ftp_h.cwd(path)
                exists = True
                self.PATH_CACHE.append(path)
            except ftplib.error_perm, e:
                if str(e.args).count('550'):    
                    exists = False
        else:
            exists = True

        return exists


    def ftp_mkdirs(self, path, sep='/'):
        '''mkdirs function for ftp handler'''
        split_path = path.split(sep)

        new_dir = ''
        for server_dir in split_path:
            if server_dir:
                new_dir += sep + server_dir
                if not self.ftp_exists(new_dir):
                    try:
                        print 'Attempting to create directory (%s) ...' % (new_dir),
                        self.ftp_h.mkd(new_dir)
                        print 'Done!'
                    except Exception, e:
                        print 'ERROR -- %s' % (str(e.args))                


def _get_local_files(local_dir, walk=False):
    '''Retrieve local files list
    result_list == a list of dictionaries with path and mtime keys. ex: {'path':<filepath>,'mtime':<file last modified time>}
    ignore_dirs == a list of directories to ignore, should not include the base_dir.
    ignore_files == a list of files to ignore.
    ignore_file_ext == a list of extentions to ignore. 
    ''' 
    result_list = []   

    ignore_dirs = ['CVS', '.svn']
    ignore_files = ['.project', '.pydevproject']
    ignore_file_ext = ['.pyc']

    base_dir = os.path.abspath(local_dir)

    for current_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
        for this_dir in ignore_dirs:
            if this_dir in dirs:
                dirs.remove(this_dir)

        sub_dir = current_dir.replace(base_dir, '')
        if not walk and sub_dir:
            break

        for this_file in files:
            if this_file not in ignore_files and os.path.splitext(this_file)[-1].lower() not in ignore_file_ext:
                filepath = os.path.join(current_dir, this_file)
                file_monitor_dict = {
                                     'path': filepath, 
                                     'mtime': os.path.getmtime(filepath)
                                     } 
                result_list.append(file_monitor_dict)
    return result_list 


def monitor_and_ftp(server, 
                      username, 
                      password, 
                      local_dir, 
                      remote_dir, 
                      encrypt=False, 
                      walk=False):
    '''Monitor local files and when an update is found connect and upload'''
    print 'Monitoring changes in (%s).' % (os.path.abspath(local_dir))
    print '(Use ctrl-c to exit)'

    last_files_list = _get_local_files(local_dir)

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(SLEEP_SECONDS)

            latest_files_list = _get_local_files(local_dir)

            files_to_update = []

            for idx in xrange(len(latest_files_list)):

                if idx < len(last_files_list):
                    # compare last modified times
                    if latest_files_list[idx]['mtime'] > last_files_list[idx]['mtime']:
                        files_to_update.append(latest_files_list[idx])

                else:
                    # add the file to the list (new file)
                    files_to_update.append(latest_files_list[idx])

            if files_to_update:
                print
                print 'Detected NEW or CHANGED file(s), attempting to send ...'
                print
                is_success = upload_all(server,
                                        username,
                                        password,
                                        local_dir, 
                                        remote_dir, 
                                        files_to_update, 
                                        encrypt, 
                                        walk)

                if not is_success:
                    break

            else:
                print '.',

            last_files_list = latest_files_list[:] # copy the list to hold
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print
            print 'Exiting.'
            break


def upload_all(server, 
                username, 
                password, 
                base_local_dir, 
                base_remote_dir, 
                files_to_update=None, 
                encrypt=False, 
                walk=False):
    '''Upload all files in a given directory to the given remote directory'''
    continue_on = False
    login_ok = False
    server_connect_ok = False

    base_local_dir = os.path.abspath(base_local_dir)
    base_remote_dir = os.path.normpath(base_remote_dir)

    if files_to_update:
        local_files = files_to_update
    else:
        local_files = _get_local_files(base_local_dir, walk)

    if local_files:
        if not encrypt: # Use standard FTP
            ftp_h = ftplib.FTP()
        else: # Use sftp
            ftp_h = psftplib.SFTP()

        try:
            ftp_h.connect(server)
            server_connect_ok = True
        except socket.gaierror, e:
            print 'ERROR -- Could not connect to (%s): %s' % (server, str(e.args))
        except IOError, e:
            print 'ERROR -- File not found: %s' % (str(e.args))
        except socket.error, e:
            print 'ERROR -- Could not connect to (%s): %s' % (server, str(e.args))

        ftp_path_tools = FtpAddOns(ftp_h)

        if server_connect_ok:
            try:
                ftp_h.login(username,password)
                print 'Logged into (%s) as (%s)' % (server, username)
                login_ok = True
            except ftplib.error_perm, e:
                print 'ERROR -- Check Username/Password: %s' % (str(e.args))
            except psftplib.ProcessTimeout, e:
                print 'ERROR -- Check Username/Password (timeout): %s' % (str(e.args))

            if login_ok:

                for file_info in local_files:
                    filepath = file_info['path']

                    path, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
                    remote_sub_path = path.replace(base_local_dir, '')
                    remote_path = path.replace(base_local_dir, base_remote_dir)
                    remote_path = remote_path.replace('\\', '/') # Convert to unix style

                    if not ftp_path_tools.ftp_exists(remote_path):
                        ftp_path_tools.ftp_mkdirs(remote_path)

                    # Change to directory
                    try:
                        ftp_h.cwd(remote_path)
                        continue_on = True
                    except ftplib.error_perm, e:
                        print 'ERROR -- %s' % (str(e.args))
                    except psftplib.PsFtpInvalidCommand, e:
                        print 'ERROR -- %s' % (str(e.args))                        

                    if continue_on:
                        if os.path.exists(filepath):
                            f_h = open(filepath,'rb')
                            filename = os.path.split(f_h.name)[-1]

                            display_filename = os.path.join(remote_sub_path, filename)
                            display_filename = display_filename.replace('\\', '/')

                            print 'Sending (%s) ...' % (display_filename),
                            send_cmd = 'STOR %s' % (filename)
                            try:
                                ftp_h.storbinary(send_cmd, f_h)
                                f_h.close()
                                print 'Done!' 
                            except Exception, e:
                                print 'ERROR!'
                                print str(e.args)
                                print
                        else:
                            print "WARNING -- File no longer exists, (%s)!" % (filepath)

                ftp_h.quit()
                print 'Closing Connection'
    else:
        print 'ERROR -- No files found in (%s)' % (base_local_dir)

    return continue_on


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import optparse

    default_config_file = u'ftpallcfg.py'

    # Create parser, and configure command line options to parse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-l", "--local_dir",
                      dest="local_dir",
                      help="Local Directory (Defaults to CWD)",
                      default='.')
    parser.add_option("-r", "--remote_dir",
                      dest="remote_dir",
                      help="[REQUIRED] Target Remote directory",
                      default=None)
    parser.add_option("-u", "--username",
                      dest="username",
                      help="[REQUIRED] username",
                      default=None)
    parser.add_option("-s","--server",
                      dest="server",
                      help="[REQUIRED] Server Address",
                      default=None)
    parser.add_option("-e", "--encrypt",
                      action="store_true", 
                      dest="encrypt",
                      help="Use sftp",
                      default=False)
    parser.add_option("-m", 
                      action="store_true", 
                      dest="monitor",
                      help="Keep process open and monitor changes",
                      default=False)
    parser.add_option("-w", 
                      action="store_true", 
                      dest="walkdir",
                      help="Walk sub directories of the given directory to find files to send.",
                      default=False)      


    (options,args) = parser.parse_args()

    if (options.username and options.server and options.remote_dir) or \
        os.path.exists(default_config_file):
        local_dir = options.local_dir

        if os.path.exists(default_config_file):
            sys.path.append('.')
            import ftpallcfg
            try:
                server = ftpallcfg.server
                username = ftpallcfg.username
                remote_dir = ftpallcfg.remote_dir
                encrypt = ftpallcfg.encrypt
                monitor = ftpallcfg.monitor
                walk = ftpallcfg.walk
            except AttributeError, e:
                print "ERROR --", str(e.args)
                print
                print 'Value(s) missing in %s file!  The following values MUST be included:' % (default_config_file)
                print '================================'
                print 'server = <server to ftp to>'
                print 'username = <Username for access to given server>'
                print 'remote_dir = <remote server directory>'
                print 'encrypt= True/False'
                print 'monitor = True/False'
                print 'walk == True/False'
                print '================================' 
                sys.exit()
        else:
            server = options.server
            username = options.username
            remote_dir = options.remote_dir
            encrypt = options.encrypt
            monitor = options.monitor
            walk = options.walkdir

        # get the user password
        prompt = 'Password (%s@%s): ' % (username, server)

        if os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno()):
            p = getpass.getpass(prompt)
        else:
            #p = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
            p = raw_input(prompt).rstrip()


        if options.encrypt:
            print '>> Using sftp for secure transfers <<'
            print 

        if monitor:
            try:
                monitor_and_ftp(server,username,p,local_dir, remote_dir, encrypt, walk)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print 'Exiting...'
        else:  
            try:
                upload_all(server, username, p, local_dir, remote_dir, [], encrypt, walk)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print 'Exiting...'            

    else:
        print 'ERROR -- Required option not given!'
        print __revision__
        print __doc__
        print
        parser.print_help()
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I created a small standalone script: https://bitbucket.org/renficiaud/yayi/src/389f19e5701cabbae46dd7a51218b8ab044ab920/plugins/project_management/common/ftp_transfer.py?at=SWD-264

Comment: @Raffi your link is dead.

Comment: Updated link [here](https://bitbucket.org/renficiaud/yayi/src/6797a73f86abb18a67abf298a6fd04e2b7ae6766/plugins/project_management/common/ftp_transfer.py?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 26):

I recently came into this problem and figured out a recursive function to solve it.

```
import ftplib
import os

server = 'localhost'
username = 'generic_user'
password = 'password'
myFTP = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
myPath = r'c:\temp'
def uploadThis(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    for f in files:
        if os.path.isfile(path + r'\{}'.format(f)):
            fh = open(f, 'rb')
            myFTP.storbinary('STOR %s' % f, fh)
            fh.close()
        elif os.path.isdir(path + r'\{}'.format(f)):
            myFTP.mkd(f)
            myFTP.cwd(f)
            uploadThis(path + r'\{}'.format(f))
    myFTP.cwd('..')
    os.chdir('..')
uploadThis(myPath) # now call the recursive function
```

Comment: by far best solution i could find, self contained and not dependant on other modules! nice work

Comment: Nice, one small issue: using `os.path.join` would make sure that your code does not depend on the operating system.

Comment: If you encounter problems, change all path + r'\{}'.format(f) to simply f. That way it worked for me - the original did not.

Comment: The most elegant solution I have found. Worked like a charm. +1

Comment: error: tplib.error_temp: 426 Transfer aborted. Interrupted system call

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 20/12/2017:**

I have written a project in GitHub for this purpose. [Click for details!](https://github.com/ceylanb/NetPubPy)

---

There are good answers above but i also want to add a good one using [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation) package. If you need to upload files from local directory to ftp directory, you can use this recursive function:

```
def upload_dir(localDir, ftpDir):
list = os.listdir(localDir)
for fname in list:
    if os.path.isdir(localDir + fname):             
        if(ftp_host.path.exists(ftpDir + fname) != True):                   
            ftp_host.mkdir(ftpDir + fname)
            print(ftpDir + fname + " is created.")
        upload_dir(localDir + fname + "/", ftpDir + fname + "/")
    else:               
        if(ftp_host.upload_if_newer(localDir + fname, ftpDir + fname)):
            print(ftpDir + fname + " is uploaded.")
        else:
            print(localDir + fname + " has already been uploaded.")
```

If you decide to use this function, you have to connect ftp using ftputil package. For this, you can use this snippet:

```
with ftputil.FTPHost("ftp_host", "ftp_username", "ftp_password") as ftp_host:
```

So, we're almost done. The last thing is usage of the function for beginners like me:

```
local_dir = "D:/Projects/.../"
ftp_dir = "/.../../"

upload_dir(local_dir, ftp_dir)
```

The most important thing is "/" character at the end of paths. You need to put it at the end. Finally, i want to share entire code:

```
with ftputil.FTPHost("ftp_host", "ftp_username", "ftp_password") as ftp_host:
    def upload_dir(localDir, ftpDir):
    list = os.listdir(localDir)
    for fname in list:
        if os.path.isdir(localDir + fname):             
            if(ftp_host.path.exists(ftpDir + fname) != True):                   
                ftp_host.mkdir(ftpDir + fname)
                print(ftpDir + fname + " is created.")
            upload_dir(localDir + fname + "/", ftpDir + fname + "/")
        else:               
            if(ftp_host.upload_if_newer(localDir + fname, ftpDir + fname)):
                print(ftpDir + fname + " is uploaded.")
            else:
                print(localDir + fname + " has already been uploaded.")
    local_dir = "D:/Projects/.../"
    ftp_dir = "/.../../"

    upload_dir(local_dir, ftp_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great for me. If you run into issues, make sure you have the `/` at the end of `local_dir` and `ftp_dir`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you try [ftpsync.py](http://code.google.com/p/ftpsync2d/). If this one doesn't helps, try google search on python ftpsync and you get a lot of answers.

Comment: I added ".py" to the link here, because there is already a GNU `ftpsync`, which is a Perl script, found at http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ftpsync

Answer (score 3):

using [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac):

```
import os
import ftputil
import ftputil.session

def upload_dir(root):
    root = unicode(root, 'utf-8')
    for dir_name, _, dir_files in os.walk(root):
        local = os.path.join(os.curdir, dir_name)
        remote = ftp_host.path.join(ftp_host.curdir, dir_name)

        if not ftp_host.path.exists(remote):
            print 'mkdir:', local, '->', remote
            ftp_host.mkdir(remote)

        for f in dir_files:
            local_f = os.path.join(local, f)
            remote_f = ftp_host.path.join(remote, f)
            print 'upload:', local_f, '->', remote_f
            ftp_host.upload(local_f, remote_f)

sf = ftputil.session.session_factory(use_passive_mode=True)

with ftputil.FTPHost('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS', session_factory=sf) as ftp_host:
    upload_dir('DIR')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to use lftp to upload folders to an FTP. I use this in my Python script to move folders to FTP

Python script:
    #! /usr/bin/python

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["bash", ftp_script, username, password, ftp, folder_to_move, src,folder_name_in_destination])
```

ftp_script:

```
lftp -u $1,$2 $3 <<EOF

mkdir $4
lcd $5 
cd $6 
mirror --reverse  
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer using [ftputil](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/). And [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for figuring out the local path.

I've compiled and improved some of the above answers.
So thank you for the inspiration!

```
import os
import ftplib
import ftputil
from pathlib import Path


def ftp_upload(ftp_host, src_path, dst_path=None):
    if dst_path is None:
         ftp_host.path.join(os.curdir)

    # Make sure that local path is a directory
    if src_path.is_dir():
        # Make sure that the root path exists
        if ftp_host.path.exists(dst_path) is False:
            # Inform user
            print(f'mkdir: {src_path} -> {dst_path}')

            # Create folder
            ftp_host.mkdir(dst_path)

        # Parse content of the root folder
        for src_child in src_path.iterdir():
            if src_child.is_dir():
                # Use recursion for sub folders/files
                dst_child = ftp_host.path.join(dst_path, src_child.stem)
                ftp_upload(ftp_host, src_child, dst_child)

            else:
                # Copy sub files
                dst_child = ftp_host.path.join(dst_path, src_child.name)

                # Inform user
                print(f'upload: {src_child} -> {dst_child}')

                # Perform copy (upload)
                ftp_host.upload(src_child, dst_child)
                # ftp_host.upload_if_newer(src_child, dst_child)

    else:
        # Inform user
        print(f"src_path: '{src_path}' must be an existing directory!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # FTP settings
    user = "ftp_user"
    password = "ftp_password"
    host = "localhost"
    port = 2121

    # Path settings
    src_path = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / "upload_dir"
    dst_dir = "upload_dir"

    # Inform user
    print(f"Establishing FTP session as '{user}'")

    # Establish FTP session
    ftplib.FTP.port = port
    with ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, password) as ftp_host:
        # Perform recursive FTP upload
        dst_path = ftp_host.path.join(os.curdir, dst_dir)
        ftp_upload(ftp_host, src_path, dst_path)
```